# When looking at the differences between X-Auth-Token vs Authorization headers, which is preferred?

Tags: http, http-headers, spring-restcontroller

What is the difference between the two headers below?
Which one is preferred?

1. `X-Auth-Token : dadas123sad12`
2. `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==`

Comment: Hi Deepak, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's quite a broad question - can you explain what you know about the two different authorization headers already, and how/why you need to choose between them?

Comment: I just want to know difference between two. In order to attach it with JWT token from rest full service. So confused to use which type of header.                 @VinceBowdren

Comment: Basically, the Authorization: Basic is used to log in and then you return a generated token which is returned on further requests to prove who you are.

Comment: @G_V : do they server exactly the same purpose? I understand that 'x-auth-token' is used for exchanging auth-token once the user has logged in with credentials. Not sure about 'Authorization: Basic'..

Comment: @user18853 'Authorization: Basic' = send user:pass to get a token. 'x-auth-token' = send the token.

Answer (score 65):

`Authorization` is the primary header used by clients to *authenticate* against peers in HTTP as foreseen in [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235). It is often linked to the `Basic` authentication scheme as per [RFC 7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617), but that is not a given.

The `Basic` scheme allows clients to provide a username-password-pair separated by a colon (`:`) coded in Base64. It cannot be stressed enough that this is a *transport coding* that provides no real security benefits. E.g. the example given by you can trivially be 'decrypted' into `Aladdin:open sesame`.

Through the [IANA HTTP Authentication Scheme Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml) (see also: [RFC 7235, sec. 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-5.1)) you will find the `Bearer` scheme (defined in RFC 6750), which is closely tied to OAuth 2.0. `X-Auth-Token` is pretty much providing a shortcut here as it (presumably) does not rely on either OAuth or the HTTP authentication framework.

Please note that with `X-Auth-Token` being an [unregistered header](https://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml), it is subject to no formal specification and its presence and content is always tied to a respective application. No general assumptions can be made on it.

Answer (score 33):

'Authorization: Basic ' means basic authentication, browser/client have to supply the username/password with each request.

In case of 'x-auth-token' user has to supply username/password for the first time and server returns a access-token in header field 'x-auth-token'. For further sessions this token is exchanged, not the username/password.

Comment: "n case of 'x-auth-token' …" How can you know that? It's a non-standard authentication scheme outside [the official auth framework](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235).

Comment: @DaSourcerer Its been a while I looked into this matter, but did verify the implementation in Spring framework (for both Basic authentication and x-auth-token) and it stands correct.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I didn't realise this question had been specific to Spring; I simply assumed the general case.

Answer (score 1):

In case of normal "Basic" Authorization, you need to provide a string like this

```
"Basic " + Buffer.from("username:password").toString("base64");
```

For client-side JavaScript you can check `window.atob()` function to encode a string in base64.

And in case of X-Authorization the user has to pass their username/password to the server for the first time and server responds with this  `X-Authorization` token, after that every api-calls the user does(in that session), it only uses that X-auth token and not their credentials.

Answer (score -2):

[**Solution**]
When you get the below response you have to put the "Bearer" as a prefix with the Outh token.

```
{    "errorCode": 401,
"errorDesc": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
"_userDesc": "Unauthorized"}
```

Should be the **Authorization** header as below

```
Bearer  eyJraWQiOiJrOTgwMy4xNTk5ODQyODg3IiwiYWxnIjoiUlM1MTIifQ....
```

Issue will be resolve..
Thanks

Comment: to what problem is this a solution?